# Visualizing UAV 3D LiDAR scan with octomap on RVIZ

Tags: python, c++, gps, ros, octomap

I have a UAV with a LiDAR onboard flying and scanning on 3D space. I have the UAV's GPS position with good precision, and I wanted to know how to build a 3D map using the LiDAR's pointCloud. Our goal is for the UAV to avoid obstacles in front of it, and it would be very helpful in visualizing the operation remotely.

I have ardupilot's GPS and orientation data through mavlink and publish it on ROS for my application, as well as the LiDAR's scan as a PointCloud2. Can I somehow set a GPS static origin and build a map around it, using something like octomap_server?

Any tips on what to look for would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

The `octomap_server` will assume the origin is (0,0) and try to build a map around that. As your question implies, if you're using the lidar for object detection and avoidance, you should **not** be operating in the GPS frame. If you're trying to use the lidar and with `octomap_server` for a long term data reference, this work should be done in the `map` frame; here you shouldn't have any issues with setting default points. If you would like to just use it for a short term reference and continuous object avoidance, it should be done in the `odom` frame; again, default position shouldn't be a problem here.